# Google Actions - Show a contact card to user through google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Is there a way to show a contact card on Google Assistant by fetching the correct contact from the contacts app based on user's rawinput?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if the Assistant on your mobile device has access to the Contacts app on the same mobile device - no.

*However*, you do have access to the user's contacts through the [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/). This has the advantage that, once they grant you permission through Account Linking, you'll be able to access their contacts through any of their Google Assistant devices - not just their mobile device.